# Integrating opencv 3.0.0 in ubuntu for python and c++ and building lib using cmake

Tags: python, c++, opencv, ubuntu, computer-vision

Please help me install opencv dev version 3.0.0 in ubuntu 14.04 and how to make build folder in opencv and create libraries. I earlier used 2.4.9 in ubuntu, things went fine but i need 3.0.0 as i need new commands which is included in it. so how to integrate opencv 3.0.0 and remove 2.4.9 completely?

what to do if this method does not give proper build/release folder?

Building OpenCV from Source Using CMake, Using the Command Line
Create a temporary directory, which we denote as , where you want to put the generated Makefiles, project files as well the object files and output binaries.

Enter the  and type

```
cmake [<some optional parameters>] <path to the OpenCV source directory>
```

For example

```
cd ~/opencv
mkdir release
cd release
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

Enter the created temporary directory () and proceed with:

```
make -j8 # -j8 runs 8 jobs in parallel.
     # Change 8 to number of hardware threads available.
sudo make install
```

Comment: Hey, what do you mean, 3.0.0 ? On the website (http://opencv.org/), there is nothing today about a new release since 2.4.9 ?

Comment: kebs, 3.0 is the [master](https://github.com/itseez/opencv) branch, 2.4.9 the stable one.

Comment: user3623269, if you forked/cloned the github repo, all it needs is a `git checkout master` (and probably a pull to update) and a rebuild

Comment: @berak i cloned it from git but after following instructions on the opencv page [link](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_install/linux_install.html) my build or release directory did not had any .lib or .so files which i can use to link to my codeblocks linker files. So please tell me how to make the build directory properly and what and how to remove the unnecessary programs/files.

Comment: impossible, if you don't tell, where(and why) it stopped (and no, i'm not going to rewrite the tutorial for you)

Comment: actually the lib folder inside the build/release folder was empty after executing the commands on the opencv page. any link how to make build after cloning from github? @berak

Comment: edit your question, add the cmake output and the error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installation in Linux
These steps have been tested for Ubuntu 10.04 but should work with other distros as well.

Required Packages

```
GCC 4.4.x or later
CMake 2.8.7 or higher
Git
GTK+2.x or higher, including headers (libgtk2.0-dev)
pkg-config
Python 2.6 or later and Numpy 1.5 or later with developer packages (python-dev, python-numpy)
ffmpeg or libav development packages: libavcodec-dev, libavformat-dev, libswscale-dev
[optional] libtbb2 libtbb-dev
[optional] libdc1394 2.x
[optional] libjpeg-dev, libpng-dev, libtiff-dev, libjasper-dev, libdc1394-22-dev
```

The packages can be installed using a terminal and the following commands or by using Synaptic Manager:

```
[compiler] sudo apt-get install build-essential
[required] sudo apt-get install cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
[optional] sudo apt-get install python-dev python-numpy libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libdc1394-22-dev
```

Getting OpenCV Source Code

You can use the latest stable OpenCV version or you can grab the latest snapshot from our Git repository.

```
Getting the Latest Stable OpenCV Version
Go to our downloads page.
Download the source archive and unpack it.
Getting the Cutting-edge OpenCV from the Git Repository
Launch Git client and clone OpenCV repository. If you need modules from OpenCV contrib repository then clone it too.
```

For example

```
cd ~/<my_working_directory>
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib.git
Building OpenCV from Source Using CMake
```

Create a temporary directory, which we denote as , where you want to put the generated Makefiles, project files as well the object files and output binaries and enter there.

For example

```
cd ~/opencv
mkdir build
cd build
Configuring. Run cmake [<some optional parameters>] <path to the OpenCV source directory>
```

For example

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
or cmake-gui





set full path to OpenCV source code, e.g. /home/user/opencv
set full path to <cmake_build_dir>, e.g. /home/user/opencv/build
set optional parameters
run: “Configure”
run: “Generate”
```

Description of some parameters

```
build type: CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release\Debug
to build with modules from opencv_contrib set OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH to <path to opencv_contrib/modules/>
set BUILD_DOCS for building documents
set BUILD_EXAMPLES to build all examples
```

[optional] Building python. Set the following python parameters:

```
PYTHON2(3)_EXECUTABLE = <path to python>
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR = /usr/include/python<version>
PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR2 = /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/python<version>
PYTHON_LIBRARY = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython<version>.so
PYTHON2(3)_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS = /usr/lib/python<version>/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/
[optional] Building java.
```

Unset parameter: BUILD_SHARED_LIBS

It is useful also to unset BUILD_EXAMPLES, BUILD_TESTS, BUILD_PERF_TESTS - as they all will be statically linked with OpenCV and can take a lot of memory.
Build. From build directory execute make, recomend to do it in several threads

For example

```
make -j7 # runs 7 jobs in parallel
[optional] Building documents. Enter <cmake_build_dir/doc/> and run make with target “html_docs”
```

For example

```
cd ~/opencv/build/doc/
make -j7 html_docs
```

To install libraries, from build directory execute

```
sudo make install
[optional] Running tests
```

Get the required test data from OpenCV extra repository.
For example

```
git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_extra.git
set OPENCV_TEST_DATA_PATH environment variable to <path to opencv_extra/testdata>.
execute tests from build directory.
```

For example

`<cmake_build_dir>/bin/opencv_test_core`

Credits: OpenCV Installation page.